# Seahorse passwords disappeared after changing keyring password

Tags: linux, debian, gnome, gnome3, gnome-keyring

I always backup my passwords on Debian Jessie by opening seahorse, changing the password of the login keyring to nothing, backing up ~/.local/share/keyrings/login.keyring and then changing the password back.

However the latest time I did this I noticed after some time after this process that all the passwords were gone. I tried changing the password of the keyring to nothing and copying the backup back to ~/.local/share/keyrings/login.keyring, but even after restarting seahorse doesn't show the passwords. Even adding passwords manually to the .keyring file doesn't get recognized by seahorse anymore. Did seahorse get updated to use some kind of checksum?

Since my backup is in plaintext I can at least manually look up my passwords, but there are waaay too many to enter them again manually. Any ideas how I can get my passwords back into the keyring? Maybe a third party tool that can import gnome keyrings or something?

**UPDATE:**
Just found that syslog says **"keyring was in an invalid or unrecognized format: /home/user/.local/share/keyrings/login.keyring"**. No surprise the keys don't show up then. Just have to figure out why it doesn't like the format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there was just an unnecessary \n in the middle of a password. No idea how it got there, since I never opened the file.